# Error handling in node js backend

Tags: node.js, ajax, error-handling, promise

I'm using a node.js backend and I got some problems with the error handling.

In the backend I use express for routing. I get a ajax post from the frontend with a array and some data in it. This data should be saved in the database. If there is an error by adding the data to the DB I get the error message in the backend but I also want so send a message to the frontend. I was try and erroring around but in the frontend I always get 'succesfull'.
This is my code till now.

Backend:

```
router.post('/tagging', function(req, res) {
  var taggedData = req.body;

  var actions = taggedData.map(element => {
    addTaggedData.addTaggedData(element)
      .then(function(result) {
        return result;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        if (err.code == "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE") {
          console.log("Tagged data contains unknown project name");
          res.send("ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE");
        } else {
          res.send(err);
        }
      })
  });
  Promise.all(actions)
    .then(
      res.send("Successful")
    )
    .catch(function(err) {
      if (err.code == "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE") {
        console.log("Tagged data contains unknown project name");
        res.send("ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE");
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }
    });
})
```

Frontend ajax call:

```
function postTaggedData(taggedData) {
$.ajax({
    url: server_connection.url + '/tagging',
    type: 'POST',
    encoding: "UTF-8",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(taggedData),
    success: function(data) {
        if (data === "Successful") {
            console.log("Tagged Data successfully send to server");
        }else if(data == "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE"){
            alert("Unknown project");
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        if(error == "Internal Server Error"){
            alert("There is an error with the server");
        }else if(error == "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE"){
            alert("Unknown project");
        }else{
            alert("There was an error while sending the Tagged Data to the server");
            console.log(xhr, "Status: ", status, error);
        }

    }
})
```

}

Comment: return statement is missing  before addTaggedData.addTaggedData(element)

Answer (score 2):

Even though you're sending error as a response, express doesn't know it's an error, so it sends it with status code `200` which means OK, so front-end thinks, response was successful.

Try setting the non-ok status and then sending an error like this: `res.status(404).send(err)`. Where `404` is a status code for "`Not Found`"

You can find more about status codes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

You can find more about express error handling [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)